# pixel distance on trees

Tags: r, performance, tree

Here is my tree. The first column is an identifier for the branch, where `0` is the trunk, `L` is the first branch on the left and `R` is the first branch on the right. `LL` is the branch on the extreme left after the second bifurcation, etc.. the variable `length` contains the length of each branch.

```
> tree
  branch length
1      0     20
2      L     12
3     LL     19
4      R     19
5     RL     12
6    RLL     10
7    RLR     12
8     RR     17
```

and here is a drawing of this tree

[image]

Here are two positions on this tree

```
pos1 = tree[3,]; pos1$length = 12
pos2 = tree[6,]; pos2$length = 3
```

I built this algorithm to calculate the shortest distance along the branches between any two points on the tree.

```
distance = function(tree, pos1, pos2){
    if (identical(pos1$branch, pos2$branch)){Dist=pos1$length-pos2$length;return(Dist)}
    pos1path = strsplit(pos1$branch, "")[[1]]
    if (pos1path[1]!="0") {pos1path = c("0", pos1path)}
    pos2path = strsplit(pos2$branch, "")[[1]]
    if (pos2path[1]!="0") {pos2path = c("0", pos1path)}
    CommonTrace="included"; for (i in 1:min(length(pos1path), length(pos2path))) {if (pos1path[i] != pos2path[i]) {CommonTrace = i-1; break}}

    if(CommonTrace=="included"){
        CommonTrace = min(length(pos1path), length(pos2path))
        if (length(pos1path) > length(pos2path)) {longerpos = pos1; shorterpos = pos2; longerpospath = pos1path} else {longerpos = pos2; shorterpos = pos1; longerpospath = pos2path}
        distToNode = 0
        if ((CommonTrace+1) != length(longerpospath)){
            for (i in (CommonTrace+1):(length(longerpospath)-1)){ distToNode = distToNode + tree$length[tree$branch == paste(longerpospath[2:i], collapse='')]} 
        }
        Dist = distToNode + longerpos$length + (tree[tree$branch == shorterpos$branch,]$length-shorterpos$length)
        if (identical(shorterpos, pos1)){Dist=-Dist}
        return(Dist)
    } else { # if they are sisterbranch
        Dist=0 
        if((CommonTrace+1) != length(pos1path)){
            for (i in (CommonTrace+1):(length(pos1path)-1)){ Dist = Dist + tree$length[tree$branch == paste(pos1path[2:i], collapse='')]}   
        }
        if((CommonTrace+1) != length(pos2path)){
            for (i in (CommonTrace+1):(length(pos2path)-1)){ Dist = Dist + tree$length[tree$branch == paste(pos2path[2:i], collapse='')]}
        }
        Dist = Dist + pos1$length + pos2$length # signdistance does not apply!
        return(Dist)
    }
}
```

I think the algorithm works fine. I then just loop through all positions of interest.

```
for (i in allpositions){
   for (j in allpositions){
      mat[i,j] = distance(tree, i, j)
   }
}
```

The issue is that I have very big trees with about 50000 positions and I would like to calculate the distance between any two positions, that is I have several times 50000^2 distances to compute. It takes forever! Can you help me to improve my code?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: You probably did, but I need to ask... Are you sure you explored all possibilities in terms of packages that could be helpful to do that? I'm thinking maybe igraph or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **provisional answer** intended to help the OP identify the problem in his algorithm.

I've added `cats` after each loop; Run the code and look at the newly created `tree_cat.txt` file, it will give you hints on where the problems might be. Individual cells in the m matrix (`m[1, 1]` for instance) are written and written over many times. So something is to be checked with the indices.

The good news is that there are 121*121 = 14641 operations of writing in matrix cells. So the problem is really about the indexing used when assigning new matrix values.

```
tree <- read.table(text="branch length
1      0     20
2      L     12
3     LL     19
4      R     19
5     RL     12
6    RLL     10
7    RLR     12
8     RR     17", header=TRUE)

m = matrix(0, ncol=sum(tree$length), nrow=sum(tree$length))
catn <- function(...) cat(..., "\n")
capture.output(
for (originbranch in 1:nrow(tree)) {
    catn("originbranch = ", originbranch)
    for (originpatch in 1:tree$length[originbranch]) {
        catn("  originpatch = ", originpatch)
        for (destinationbranch in 1:nrow(tree)) {
            catn("    destinationbranch = ", destinationbranch)
            for (destinationpatch in 1:tree$length[destinationbranch]){
                catn("      destinationpatch = ", destinationpatch)
                split_dest = unlist(strsplit(tree$branch[destinationbranch], ""))
                split_orig =  unlist(strsplit(tree$branch[originbranch], ""))
                depth = 0
                for (i in 1:min(c(length(split_orig), length(split_dest)))) {
                    catn("        i = ", i)
                    if (split_dest[i] == split_orig[i]){
                        depth = depth + 1
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
                distdest = 0
                distorig = 0
                for (upperbranch in depth:length(split_orig)){
                    catn("        upperbranch_orig = ", upperbranch)
                    distorig = distorig + tree$length[tree$branch == paste(split_orig[1:upperbranch], collapse="")]
                }
                for (upperbranch in depth:length(split_dest)){
                    catn("        upperbranch_dest = ", upperbranch)
                    distdest = distdest + tree$length[tree$branch == paste(split_dest[1:upperbranch], collapse="")]
                }
                distorig = distorig + destinationpatch - tree$length[originbranch]
                distdest = distdest + destinationpatch - tree$length[destinationbranch]
                dist = distorig + distdest
                m[originpatch, destinationpatch] = dist ## PROBLEMATIC INDEXING!!
                catn(sprintf("        ----->   Matrix element written: m[%d, %d] = %d", originpatch, destinationpatch, dist))
            }
        }
    }
}, file = "tree_cat.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your concept of pixel distance, but based on my understanding, the code below provides a function pixel_dist which calculates the pixel distance between two pixel points specified along tree branches.

I've used igraph to map your tree to a graph where the branches are graph edges and graph vertices are branch intersections and use the graph functions to do the basic vertex distance calculations.

```
library(igraph)
#  Assign vertex name to tree branch intersections
temp <- gsub("R","1", gsub("L","0",tree$branch))
temp <- strsplit(temp,split=character(0))
tree$upper_vert <- sapply(temp, function(x) {n <- length(x);  2^n + 2^((n-1):0)%*%as.numeric(x) }  )
tree$lower_vert <- as.integer(tree$upper_vert/2)
tree$branch[tree$branch=="0"] <- "trunk"
tree[tree$branch=="trunk",c("lower_vert","upper_vert")] <- c(0,1)

#  Create graph of tree
tree_graph <- graph.data.frame(tree[,c("lower_vert","upper_vert")], directed=TRUE)    # CORRECTED
E(tree_graph)$label <- paste(tree$branch, tree$length,sep="-")
E(tree_graph)$branch <- tree$branch
E(tree_graph)$length <- tree$length
E(tree_graph)$weight <- tree$length
#
#  assign x & y positions for plotting
#
V(tree_graph)$y <- as.integer(as.numeric(V(tree_graph)$name)^.5) + 1
V(tree_graph)["0"]$y <- 0
V(tree_graph)["1"]$y <- 1
V(tree_graph)$x <- as.numeric(V(tree_graph)$name) - 3*(2^(V(tree_graph)$y-2)) + .5
V(tree_graph)["0"]$x <- 0
V(tree_graph)["1"]$x <- 0
plot(tree_graph)
#
#  calculate distances between vertices
#
vert_dist <- shortest.paths(tree_graph, weights=V(tree_graph)$length, mode="all")  # distances between vertices
vert_dist_dir <- shortest.paths(tree_graph, weights=V(tree_graph)$length, mode="in")  # distances between vertices along directed edges ADDED
#
# Calculate distances from end vertex of each edge (branch)
#
edge_node <- get.edges(tree_graph, E(tree_graph))    #  list of vertices for each edge
brnch_dist <- sapply(edge_node[,2], function(x) vert_dist[x, edge_node[,2]])  # distance between end vertex of each edge
colnames(brnch_dist) <- E(tree_graph)$branch   
rownames(brnch_dist) <- E(tree_graph)$branch

brnch_dist_dir <- sapply(edge_node[,2], function(x) vert_dist_dir[x, edge_node[,2]])  # directed distance between end vertex of each edge - ADDED
colnames(brnch_dist_dir) <- E(tree_graph)$branch   
rownames(brnch_dist_dir) <- E(tree_graph)$branch
#
# calcuates total pixel distance given branches and pixel distances along branch  # CORRECTED
#
pixel_dist <- function(b1, pix1, b2, pix2, brnch_dist, brnch_dist_dir) { 
    if(!is.infinite(brnch_dist_dir[b1,b2]) )     #  directed edges same from b1 to b2
      pixel_dist <- brnch_dist[b1,b2] - E(tree_graph)[branch== b2]$length + E(tree_graph)[branch== b1]$length + pix2 - pix1 
    else {
      if(!is.infinite(brnch_dist_dir[b2,b1]) )   # directed edges same from b2 to b1
         pixel_dist <- brnch_dist[b1,b2] + E(tree_graph)[branch== b2]$length - E(tree_graph)[branch== b1]$length + pix2 - pix1 
    else                                         # opposing directed edges
        pixel_dist <- brnch_dist[b1,b2] - E(tree_graph)[branch== b2]$length - E(tree_graph)[branch== b1]$length + pix2 + pix1
    }
    return(pixel_dist)
}

pixel_dist(b1="L",pix1=3, b2="R", pix2=5, brnch_dist=brnch_dist, brnch_dist_dir=brnch_dist_dir)
```

A plot of the tree graph with branch names, lengths, and directions

[image]

I wasn't clear on how you intended to place pixel distances in a matrix but you could use the pixel_dist function or something like it with the prior code to calculate the matrix values.

## EDIT

The code above has been modified to properly account for edge direction in calculating pixel distance.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is unclear. I'll try to edit it to improve it. I haven't looked at the code yet but I would expect from the command `pixel_dist(b1="L",pix1=3, b2="R", pix2=5, brnch_dist=brnch_dist)` to return `8` and not `22`. It should return 8 because, there is a distance of 5, from pixel2 to the bifurcation and a distance of 3 from the pixel1 to the bifurcation. Thank you

Comment: Your comment and example helped to clarify my understanding of pixel distance.  I've tried to correct the code to properly account for edge direction and checked a number of cases including your example.  It seems to work for cases in which the tree branches are traversed in up only, down only, and up and down directions.